# Given an isometry $F$ between Lie groups, does $dF$ commute with (differentials of) left translations?

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

Let $G$ and $H$ be Lie groups equipped with left invariant metrics, and let $F \colon G \to H$ be an identity-preserving isometry.

Does the differential $dF$ commute with left translations? More precisely, if $v \in T_{e}G$ ($e$ being the identity element of $G$), is it true that

$$
\left(L_{F(p)}\right)_{\ast} \left(dF_{e}(v) \right) = dF_{p}\left( \left(L_{p}\right)_{\ast}(v) \right) \,?
$$

EDIT: An equivalent question would be: Is the image of a left invariant vector field under $dF$ also left invariant? I believe this is not true in general, but maybe under some extra assumptions on $G$ or $H$?

Comment: If $F$ is a left translation, then don't the two sides of your equality typically lie in different tangent spaces?

Comment: @JasonDeVito If $F$ preserves the identity, then both sides should lie in $T_{F(p)}H$, right? I will edit the question.